# Parse xml with php simple xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following xml file:

```
<File>
<Function name="for">
        <Function name="if">
                   <Function name="if">
                    </Function>
         </Function>
         <Function name="else">
         </Function>
</Function>
</File>
```

I'm using php Simple xml parser to get all functions from this file and display them. What i want to get is something like this :

```
for{
    if{
        if{

        }
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

So to do that it is not sufficient to get all nodes that contain a function, i need to get the order as well.

I made a class called Function that have a list of functions:

```
class Function{
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Function")
 */
private listFunctions;
```

Now every function can have nested functions.
My parsing is as follows:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$functions = array();
foreach ($xml->->File->children() as $f) {
    // Iterate over <Function> tags under <File> tag (level-1 functions)

    $function = new Function();
    $function->setName($f['name']);

    if(isset($f->Function)) {
        foreach($f->children() as $cf){
            //Iterate over level-2 functions

            $cfunction = new Function();
            $cfunction->setName($cf['name']);

            $f->addListFunctions($cfunction);
        }
    }
    $functions[] = $function;
}
```

This example works perfectly if I have two levels of nested functions, it will display the following:

```
for{
    if{

    }
    else{

    }
}
```

But I don't know hwo many levels I have, so I need to do it in a generic way.
I think the solution is to use a recursive function, but I'm not used to it, and I don't know how to start, or even if it's the right path to follow.

Any idea ?

Comment: The logic is :- put code inside a function in which  Inside first foreach check still the value is array type if yes then call this function again, if no do other stuff.